# How to get the exit code of commands started by find?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, find, exit-status

I am using "find" in a Travis-CI to check a particular file type with a program. (To be exact, it is a shellcheck check.)

However, when using `find` the exit codes of the command(s)/subshells executed by it are naturally discarded, as they are not passed to the "main script".

As an example this is a find command:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec sh ./testScripts.sh "{}" \;
```

`./testScripts.sh` may exit with 0 or >= 1, depending on the test result.

The `testScripts.sh` exits properly with the correct exit code, but due to `find` the exit code of the command is always "0". All I want is, that if **one file/execution** errors, this error is "propagated" up to Travis-CI.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you change `testScripts.sh` so it accepts multiple scripts to run? That way you could use the `-exec {} +` variant, which exits with status != 0 if the command fails.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Would need another loop in the `testScripts.sh`, but that is acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Stephen Kitt's suggestion in comments:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec sh -c 'for n; do ./testScripts.sh "$n" || exit 1; done' sh {} +
```

This will cause the `sh -c` script to exit with a non-zero exit status as soon as `testScript.sh` does. This means that `find` will also exit with a non-zero exit status:

> If terminated by a plus sign, the pathnames for which the primary
>                is evaluated are aggregated into sets, and utility will be
>                invoked once per set, similar to `xargs(1)`.  **If any invocation
>                exits with a non-zero exit status, then `find` will eventually do
>                so as well**, but this does not cause `find` to exit early.

---

Regarding the questions in comment:

1. `for n; do ... ; done` looks weird but makes sense when you realize that without anything to iterate over, the `for` loop will iterate over `"$@"` implicitly.
2. The trailing `sh` at the end will be placed in `$0` of the `sh -c` shell. The `{}` will be substituted by a number of pathnames.  Without `sh` there, the first pathname would end up in `$0` and would not be picked up by the loop, since it's not in `$@`. `$0` usually contains the name of the current interpreter (it will be used in error message produced by the `sh -c` shell).

Comment: Note the "this does not cause find to exit early.". This is important to know. Not that it matters in my case (it may actually be a good thing), but just FYI.

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in a syntax error. And I see two things I don't understand: 1. Is not the "for loop" too short. It should be "for x in y", should not it? 2. Why do you have `sh` another time at the end?

Syntax error:
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `./testScripts.sh'
sh: -c: line 0: `for n; ./testScripts.sh "$n" || exit 1; done'

Comment: @rugk Sorry, there was a `do` missing. Fixed now.

Comment: @rugk `for n; do ...; done` will iterate over the positional parameters.  These are given by `{}` on the command line after that last `sh`. The trailing `sh` will be placed in `$0`, which is _not_ a positional parameter (in the same sense as `$1` etc. are).

Comment: @rugk See also update.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It works.

One thing I noticed: In this way, it actually **does exit early** when an exit code is returned in any of the `./testScripts.sh` executions.
Also I like the `_` way more, thanks for the explanation though…

Some final questions though: 1. As having everything in one line may not be nice, is it be possible to move the "for" loop into the  `./testScripts.sh` file? 2. When `./testScripts.sh` returns an error code > 1, the `find` output is always "1". Even if I change the line to "exit $?" – it does not work. Can I keep the "correct" exit code, somehow?

Comment: Note that the `|| exit 1` exits **that** `sh` invocation but does not prevent more `sh` invocations from being started. With  `xargs`, you can use the 255 exit status to cause `xargs` to abort. See also the `-quit` predicate of GNU `find` or `-exit` predicate (which can take an exit code as argument) of netbsd.

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` will exit with an exit status between 1  and 125 (123 with GNU `xargs`), if any of the command fails, and will abort if any fails with a 255 status.

To use `xargs` reliably on the output of  `find` (with `-print0`) and preserve the command's stdin, you'd need GNU `xargs` though. So, with GNU `xargs` and a shell with support for process substitution like `ksh`, `zsh` or `bash`:

```
xargs -n1 -r0a <(find . -type f -iname '*.sh' -print0) sh ./testScripts.sh
```

Or to abort at the first failing one:

```
xargs -r0a <(find . -type f -iname '*.sh' -print0) sh -c '
  for file do
    sh ./testScripts.sh "$file" || exit 255
  done' sh
```

You can also abort `find` upon the first error with (POSIX code):

```
find . -type f -name '*.[sS][hH]' -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    if ! sh ./testScripts.sh "$file"; then
      kill -s PIPE "$PPID"
      exit 1
    fi
  done' sh {} +
```

(using SIGPIPE as a less *noisy* signal with some shells like `bash`). That will cause `find` to be killed and so return with a non-zero exit status.

To get the exact value of the exit status of the (here last) failing commmand, with `zsh` or `bash`, you can also do:

```
ret=0
while IFS= read -rd '' -u3 file; do
  sh ./testScripts.sh "$file" 3<&- || ret=$?
done 3< <(find . -type f -iname '*.sh' -print0)
```

Though with `zsh`, you don't even need `find` for that:

```
set -o extendedglob
ret=0
for file (./**/*(#i).sh(D.)) {
  ./testScripts.sh $file || ret=$?
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically it seems to use the same concept as @Kusalananda's answer, but this here looks a bit more complicated. Anyway, good to have alternatives.

Comment: @rugk, see my comment though on @Kusalananda's answer, `find` may run more than one `sh` instance depending on how many files there are, the size of the environment, and the current limit on that stacksize (if on Linux)